# How can I clean and dry a lambswool applicator quickly?

Tags: hardwood-floor, staining, polyurethane

I'm refinishing my floor, sanding / stain / poly. One of the most frustrating things is clean up. In particular, the lambswool applicator. It cleans with mineral spirits but it takes forever to dry. It's also really hard to squeeze out the stuff from it. What do the pros do?  I have a hard time believing they are constantly touching mineral spirits with their bare hands daily, but I can't wring it out very well with gloves at all. I want to make ths process more efficient. Any other tips would be awesome for setup / clean up too.

Answer (score 3):

When I did my floors I wrapped the lambswool with kitchen plastic wrap, the kind you would wrap a sandwich with. That kept it moist for at least a day. If I went several days between applications, I would just use a new lambswool. It's not good to use mineral spirits (or many other cleaners) bare handed. The health risks just are not worth it. If you don't believe that, get an MSDS sheet of the product your using and read it.

Comment: Good call.. I've been touching the mineral spirits but washing it off right away. I'm betting the pro's use the rollers and toss em. A first time applicator is supposed to be soaked in mineral spirits to remove the lint. The roller mentioned below is lintless so that solves that too. Thanks for the rec on putting in a plastic bag. I do that with my paint brushes so why didn't I think of it. Poly is disgusting, i'd rather jsut toss it each time and eat the cost of rollers honestly.

Answer (score 2):

Lambs wool applicators are great, but very old school for floor applications.  Today we use mostly mohair rollers.  A mohair roller is simply a very high quality, lint less 1/4 inch nap roller cover.  They work great with either oil or latex based urethanes.  You can but a wet roller cover in a Ziplock bag, squeeze the excess air out and the roller is good to reuse for several days.  You could do the same thing for a lambswool pad.

Comment: good call. I'm surprised. I thought the applicator was idea for having no bubbles or something. i saw your mohair roller at lowes website, maybe I'll run out there and get one for the next coat.